# Skrollr, javascript, animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched couple threads, also read the skrollr documentation but i didnt find what im searching for.

my problem is:
i want to make a (self)animation of object(image .png, simple slide from 0px; left to 1200px; right) and also make a skrollr slide effect on that object, so it looks like animated object being skrollr also ;)

.html:

```
<div id="chm1" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-600="background-position:-600px -200px;"></div>
```

.css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from{
        background-position:-600px;
    }
    to{
        background-position:1200px;
    }
}
#chm1 {
    -webkit-animation: slide 15s linear infinite;
    background:url(ch1.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:50;
    top:20%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

is it even possible to do that?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: You can't have two animations on the same property, that's undefined behavior. There's `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`, but afaik not supported in all browsers.

Comment: so You mean I should use skrollr for y-position and webkit css animation for x-position? Maybe You suggest other way to make those animations on 1 page?

Comment: You can combine `background-position` and `transform:translate()` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: well thank You :) where is that button 'solved'?

Comment: If you have code to share which solved your issue, post it as an answer and then accept your own answer.